# Div border not covering all child divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div surrounding multiple divs. The border of parent div is not covering all child divs as shown in the fiddle. Can anyone tell what is the issue here?

```
<div style="border:1px dashed gray;">
    <div style="position:relative;top:10px;"><input type="text" placeholder="https://" /></div>
    <div style="position:relative;top:30px;"><input type="text" placeholder="https://" /></div>
    <div style="position:relative;top:50px;font-size: 10px">Some content</div>
    <div style="position:relative;top:60px;background-color:#E6E0EC">
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ca3y6m72/)

Comment: If you use relative positioning, they go outside parent div - that's the whole idea in it.

Comment: I do need some gap between elements + border should cover all divs. If I remove relative, then I can't specify position from parent div.

Comment: You are moving them outside the parent div with your relative positioning. Instead of this I would suggest using margins/paddings. I don't think you need to move them in relation to the parent..

Comment: Ok. Can you explain clearly why is it covering all input tags even if I add more there, and not other divs?

Comment: @sam it's a coincidence. The outside div is sized to the size the elements take up without the `top` offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `position: relative` on the divs not surrounded by the border. The relative position property moves the contents of the element but keeps the reserved space of the element in the normal flow.

If you want to achieve the same layout with a border around everything it is best to use the `margin`property. I updated your jsfiddle to show an example

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ca3y6m72/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Did that exactly. I am accepting your answer as you provided proper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Using `top` to specify the spacing is not a good idea in a case like this. It will be fragile. Let the elements make room for themselves and let the box model make space in the parent. To do this use `margin-top` instead.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markm/rmvneo88/

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no need for position relative, in all the child divs, just remove those tags.